# Extracting live stock price using JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Can you please tell me how to extract company live stock prices of using JSP?

I already tryed without success to extract it.

Comment: What have you tried? Try to show some code and point to the concrete problem you are facing.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Uh no idea what you are asking. But you could use Yahoo finance and use an HTML parser to parse the HTMl to get the stock price.